# Spinner Widget working on Android based T.V.

Tags: android

I have question about android spinner widget.Spinner widget supports only  selection events means OnItemSelectListner and does not support OnClicklistner . Selection events and click events are different so my question is how spinner widget works on android TV ? How user points the elements in spinner on Tv and then click it it. Sorry if my question is wrong  as i am new to android development.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How user points the elements in spinner on Tv and then click it it

Typically, they will use a D-pad or arrow keys on the remote for their television. The details will vary somewhat by device.

So, for example, they would:

- Use the D-pad direction keys to highlight the `Spinner`
- Click the center D-pad button to open the `Spinner`
- Use the up/down D-pad direction keys to navigate the list
- Click the center D-pad button to make the selection

On the whole, a `Spinner` may not be the best choice for a TV user interface.

Comment: so  by using D-pad or arrow keys ,does onItemSelectListner is acting like a onClickListner after clicking the center D-Pad button to click the item in spinner ?

Comment: @sanket: No, this is still all selection events. Your Java code is the same regardless of whether the user is using a touchscreen+finger, a mouse, or a D-pad/arrow keys.